# SharePoint 2013: Web Part Disappearing (not deleted, closed, or hidden...GONE)

Tags: 2013, web-part

I'm creating a page that contains several WPs, including a Data Form WP. It will be a replica of an existing page that is in use while the new page is being developed (different data source, same UI).

The issue I've come across is with the Data Form WP. When I added and configured it on my new page, the WP on the existing page disappeared. It's not closed or hidden, it's not on the WP Maintenance Page or in the page code in Designer, it's literally just gone. I thought maybe somehow I inadvertently deleted it. Fortunately, I had the code of the existing page and pasted it back in and  thankfully it's working fine again...but my new WP on my new page disappeared as soon as I did. The WP on both pages point to different data source lists and I created mine from scratch.  I've found nothing in the WPs themselves, Google, etc. that can explain the WP not being able to be on 2 different pages so deletes itself from one or the other, so I'm at a loss.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Strange behavior. Can you check the versioning on the page itself to see if it was modified after the disappearance

Comment: @Colbs Thank you for the reply.  There was no change to the version on either page when the WP disappeared.  For example, when the WP disappeared from the existing page (last week), a new version wasn't created and the current version's last modified date was in Sept.  A new version did get created when I pasted the WP back in.